# Why do we use H in the limit here? And how do you cancel out |h|/h, is that even allowed?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

This is the original function: $f_3(x, y) = |x|e^{x^2y}$

This is the limit we used:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f_3(h, y) - f_3(0, y)}{h} & = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{|h|e^{h^2y}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} e^{h^2y} = 1\\
\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f_3(h, y) - f_3(0, y)}{h} & = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{|h|e^{h^2y}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} -e^{h^2y} = -1\
\end{align*}

Comment: Let $S(h)$ denote the sign of $h$ and be specified as $(-1)$ if $h < 0$, $(+1)$ if $h > 0$, and undefined if $h = 0$.  Re-express $|h|$ as $h \times S(h)$.

Comment: Does $h$ tend to $0$ ? If yes, the limit does not exist , since it is $1$ from the right and $-1$ from the left. But for $h>0$ , we actually can cancel $h$ out to get $1$ (analogue for the left limit).

Comment: But why do we use H instead of x?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What is $H$ in this context ?

Comment: That‘s my question, why we use H in the limit instead of x, the only information i know is, it says „if x = 0, we see that: *limits as displayed above*“

Comment: The topic is about partial differention and the limits are used to see if there is a  x-derivative

Comment: The reason why there are two limits shown is that $\frac{|h|}{h}$ can have two different values: $1$ or $-1$, depending on $h$.  If $h$ is negative (i.e., approached from the left), then it is -1.  If $h$ is positive (i.e., approached from the right), then it is 1.